# Insert XML into a specific div with C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, feedburner

I am getting XML data from feedburner and in my C# codebehind I am accessing the data like so:

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load("https://feedburner.google.com/api/awareness/1.0/GetFeedData?uri=cooklikecarolyn");
XmlNodeList subscribers = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("entry");
Response.Write(subscribers[0].Attributes["circulation"].Value.ToString());
```

How do I insert this into a div I already have at the bottom of the page?

Comment: Is this an ASP.NET WebForms application?

Comment: Do you want it to display XML or just the content?

Answer (score 1):

Set the div runat="server':

```
<div id="feedDiv" runat="server"></div>
```

Then set the InnerHtml or InnerText of the div in C#:

```
feedDiv.InnerHtml = subscribers[0].Attributes["circulation"].Value.ToString();
```